# Excel - Vlookup formula for over 500k rows - how to speed this up?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm new to this forum and need your help.

I have a few tables on my report with over 500k rows in each and need to perform multiple vlookups. With the below vlookup formula it takes me forever to do so (I need to do it for the last few years, monthly).

My formula is as below:

```
=VLOOKUP(A:A,'Oct Corrected'!A:C,2,0)
```

How can I speed these calculations up? Can I use any different formula instead?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Don't use an entire column reference. Parse that down to the used range, that should help a little bit.  Also, what do you mean ti takes forever - The calculation slows Excel?

Comment: do not use `A:A` as the lookup value, put that as the actual cell `=VLOOKUP(A2,'Oct Corrected'!A:C,2,0)` then copy it down the range.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. As I have over 500k values to search and also my database is huge, it takes me over 10 minutes for the 1 formula to be dragged down (due to calculations in excel).

Comment: Also if you have that much data, Excel is the wrong tool

Comment: Thanks Scott, that helped a bit and speeded slightly up. Sadly, I have no access to this database in SQL, therefore I must use Excel reports.

Comment: Maybe `=INDEX('Oct Corrected'!$B:$B,MATCH(A2,'Oct Corrected'!$A:$A,0))` ?

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar, it helped a bit but it still takes around 6 minutes to complete.

Comment: Scott Craner, what tool would you recommend to use?

Comment: A database would be the correct tool. You would have your `Oct Corrected` as it's own table. You would have the list of values against which you are applying this `vlookup()` as a second table. You would then join to get your results like `SELECT list_of_values.column1, oct_corrected.column2 FROM list_of_values INNER JOIN oct_corrected ON list_of_values.column1 = oct_corrected.column1;` and it would fetch those results in the blink of an eye.

Comment: Obviously getting that set up and learning SQL is a bit of a learning curve, but if you are going to routinely deal with larger data like this it's worth the pain of learning it. It's also a more marketable skill, so win-win ;)

Comment: Thanks JNevill. As I haven't got access to this dataset, I will try to speak to people who may have and maybe we can run this via SQL. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: One solution is to use a double `VLOOKUP` as this speeds up the calculation dramatically. I am not going to post as an answer as it is already very well explained here : https://exceljet.net/formula/faster-vlookup-with-2-vlookups

Comment: In my opinion if you have old data, i believe it would be static, then don't use vlookup, just use it once and then copy paste the column as values. After that use vlookup only where and when data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use macro then add like this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(A:A,'Oct Corrected'!A:C,2,0)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```